# How to correctly redesign a selection sort algorithm to a bubble sort?

Tags: c++, bubble-sort, selection-sort

I am attempting to convert the selection sort to a bubble sort. Have I done so successfully? If not, what do I need to do to correct this issue?

I believe I have converted it correctly.

#### Attempt

```
// This program demonstrates how to sort and search a
// string vector using selection sort and binary search.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
void bubbleSort (vector < string > &);
void swap (string &, string &);
int binarySearch (const vector < string > &, string);

int main ()
{
  string searchValue;       // Value to search for
  int position;         // Position of found value

  // Define a vector of strings.
  vector < string > names
  {
  "Lopez", "Smith", "Pike", "Jones",
      "Abernathy", "Hall", "Wilson", "Kimura",
      "Alvarado", "Harrison", "Geddes", "Irvine"};

  // Sort the vector.
  bubbleSort (names);

  // Display the vector's elements.
  cout << "Here are the sorted names:\n";
for (auto element:names)
    cout << element << endl;
  cout << endl;

  // Search for a name.
  cout << "Enter a name to search for: ";
  getline (cin, searchValue);
  position = binarySearch (names, searchValue);

  // Display the results.
  if (position != -1)
    cout << "That name is found at position " << position << endl;
  else
    cout << "That name is not found.\n";

  return 0;
}

//***********************************************************************
// The selectionSort function sorts a string vector in ascending order. *
//***********************************************************************
void bubbleSort (vector < string > &v)
{
  int minIndex;
  string minValue;

  for (int pass = 1; pass < v.size (); ++pass)
    {
      for (int index = 0; (index + 1) < v.size (); ++index)
    {
      if (v[index + 1] < v[index])
        {
          swap (v[index], v[index + 1]);
        }
    }
    }

//***************************************************
// The swap function swaps a and b in memory.       *
//***************************************************
  void swap (string & a, string & b)
  {
    string temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }

//***************************************************************
// The binarySearch function performs a binary search on a      *
// string vector. array, which has a maximum of size elements,  *
// is searched for the number stored in value. If the number is *
// found, its vector subscript is returned. Otherwise, -1 is    *
// returned indicating the value was not in the vector.         *
//***************************************************************

  int binarySearch (const vector < string > &v, string str)
  {
    int first = 0,      // First vector element
      last = v.size () - 1, // Last vector element
      middle,           // Mid point of search
      position = -1;        // Position of search value
    bool found = false;     // Flag

    while (!found && first <= last)
      {
    middle = (first + last) / 2;    // Calculate mid point
    if (v[middle] == str)   // If value is found at mid
      {
        found = true;
        position = middle;
      }
    else if (v[middle] > str)   // If value is in lower half
      last = middle - 1;
    else
      first = middle + 1;   // If value is in upper half
      }
    return position;
  }
```

The goal is to convert from a selection sort to a bubble sort. I have the original code that I had before attempting the conversion if that would help.

Comment: Thats selection sort.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"?  You cannot "convert" a sort algorithm to another sort algorithm.  A bubble sort is not a selection sort -- they are two different ways of sorting.  You need to start from scratch and write a bubble sort, and that is one of the easiest sorting algorithms to code (easier than selection sort).

Comment: @tkausl what do I need to do to correct this and make it bubble sort? The code was originally written with selection sort but I need to rewrite it as bubble sort.

Answer (score 1):

Bubble sort only swaps adjacent elements, so anywhere you test non adjacent elements you are diverging from bubble. The simplest form of bubble sort is of this form.

```
for (int pass = 1; pass < v.size(); ++pass) {
    for (int index = 0; (index + 1) < v.size(); ++index) {
        if (v[index + 1] < v[index]) {
            swap(v[index], v[index + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

We can note that after the first pass, the maximum value *must* be in the right place, and similarly after the second pass the second largest value is in it's place, etc. This allows us to adjust the bounds of the inner loop.

```
for (int pass = 1; pass < v.size(); ++pass) {
    for (int index = 0; (index + pass) < v.size(); ++index) {
        if (v[index + 1] < v[index]) {
            swap(v[index], v[index + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```